# Unity raycast collide object and print its name on GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting, identify

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class GuardSample : MonoBehaviour 
{
FOV2DEyes eyes;
FOV2DVisionCone visionCone;
float speed = -5;
RaycastHit hit;


void Start() 
{
    eyes = GetComponentInChildren<FOV2DEyes>();
    visionCone = GetComponentInChildren<FOV2DVisionCone>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (transform.position.x < -10 || transform.position.x > 10)
    {
        speed *= -1;
    }

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}

bool playerInView = false;

void Update()
{
    playerInView = false;
    foreach (RaycastHit hit in eyes.hits)
    {
        if (hit.transform && hit.transform.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerInView = true;
        }
    }

}

void OnGUI()
{
    if (playerInView)
    {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 160, 60), "Title");
        GUI.Label( new Rect(10, 10, 160, 60), hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }

}
```

}

My gaurd moves and when the player comes inside raycast, the GUI appear but name does not identify

everything works except "hit.collider.gameObject.name"
Unity gives error that "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

please have a look i am new in Unity and C#

Comment: it seems you are not performing raycast at all. Have a look at Physics.Raycast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have access to hit variable, because you are not storing it, you are only saving it in each iteration. A simple solution to that is to store the hit which makes `playerInView = true;`.

Something like this modifications to your Update() and OnGUI() methods must works;

```
RaycastHit hittenGo; // Declare up this variable

void Update()
{
  playerInView = false;
  foreach (RaycastHit hit in eyes.hits)
  {
    if (hit.transform && hit.transform.tag == "Player")
    {
        hittenGo = hit;
        playerInView = true;
    }
  }
}

void OnGUI()
{
  if (playerInView)
  {
    GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 160, 60), "Title");
    GUI.Label( new Rect(10, 10, 160, 60), hittenGo.collider.gameObject.name);
  }
}
```

Don't mind asking me any doubt you have about my approach.

Comment: hittenGo is a default variable of Unity or C# or what ?
just to learn

Comment: another question if you dont mind plz

in one frame it is only showing the name of one object even if there are two objects

when one object escape from the field of view of raycast only then raycast identify other object

i hope i ask question understandable :-)

Comment: You are welcome! hittenGo is just a variable that I have defined so that I can use for whatever I want.

Comment: Responding to the second comment, in that case you must create an array to store all the hitten GO. With your code you are just storing the last hitten one. So instead of creating a variable RayCastHit named hittenGo you have to create a variable wich must be an array of RayCastHit.

Comment: One more comment, hittenGo is the name of the variable which is a RayCastHit variable, where RayCastHit is a Unity engine Class. I suggest you to take a look at this Unity tutorials http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting

Comment: i add array as following

RaycastHit hittenGo = new RaycastHit();
.
.
.
.
void OnGUI()
 {
  if (playerInView)
  {
   foreach (RaycastHit hittenGo in eyes.hits)
   {
    GUI.Label( new Rect(40, 25, 100, 40), hittenGo.collider.gameObject.name);
   }
  }
  
 }

now it can detect both objects at a time
but one strange thing happened
now my objects only detect at extreme left edge of FOV rays

please have a look to the images of my scene

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025376/1.jpg
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025376/2.jpg

Comment: i tried many options but may be due to very little understanding of error this is happening
sory about that

Comment: Hi, You're not declaring an array you're just initializing an object. Here you have an example of how to create an array and how to loop it to get all of its components. https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/arrays. In the example the code shows how to create an array of Gameobjects and iterate it. Yo have to do that with RayCastHit instead of GameObjects.